# Turn a table into a data table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

I want to turn my table into a datatable so that user can read data displayed more easily and the I could add live filters to select only some type of datas. This is my code, I already wrote the code needed to make it possible.
Despite all, if the code is ran, the table isn't dinamic and doesn't turn into a datatable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>FILTRARE PER GENE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div>
    <div id="holder">
    <h1><?php echo "FILTRO PER GENE DELLE VARIANTI";?></h1></div>
    <hr />
    <br>


    <div id="sidebar" style="width:50%">
      <A HREF="varianti_utente.php" class="w2-bar-item w2-button">NUOVA RICERCA</A>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
      <A HREF="dati_utente.php" class="w2-bar-item w2-button">DATI UTENTE</A>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <A HREF="home.php" class="w2-bar-item w2-button">HOME</A>
      <P>&nbsp;</P>
    </div>


    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Live Search...">

    <BR>
    <form action="filtro_per_gene_selezione_per_var_RICERCA_PAZ.php" method="POST">
    GENE <select name="gene">
    <option></option>
    <option>CFH</option>
    <option>CD46</option>
    <option>CFI</option>
    <option>CFB</option>
    <option>C3</option>
    <option>ADAMTS13</option>
    <option>THBD</option>
    <option>DGKE</option>
    <input type='submit' name='vai' value'Invia'>
    </form><BR /><BR />



    <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-mid-8 col-mid-offset-2">
                     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                         <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>RISULTATO</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>dnaCode</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Chr</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Start</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>End</b></td>
                                  <td width="5%"><b>Alt</b></td>
                                  <td width="5%"><b>Ref</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Zigosity</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Gene</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Func</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Gene Context</b></td>
                                  <td width="9%"><b>Dist</b></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                                $conn= mysql_connect("local", "user", "pass");
                                if (!$conn)
                                {
                                     die("Connessione non riuscita <br>" . mysql_error());
                                //}else{
                                    //echo "Connessione al database stabilita con successo<br><br>";
                                }

                                mysql_select_db("database_var", $conn);

                                if(isset($_POST["vai"])){
                                   $dna=$_POST["dna"];
                                }
                                 $sql="SELECT V.dnaCode, V.Chr, V.Start, V.End, V.Alt, V.Ref, V.zygosity, A.gene, A.Func, A.GeneContext, A.Dist FROM variante as V JOIN annotazioni as A ON V.Start = A.Start AND V.Alt=A.Alt AND V.Ref=A.Ref WHERE V.dnaCode='" .$dna. "'";
                                 $result_gene = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
                                 $record_gene=mysql_fetch_array($result_gene);

                                 $index=1;
                                 while ($record_gene=mysql_fetch_array($result_gene)){
                                     echo '
                                        <tr>
                                          <b><td>'.$index.'</td></b>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['dnaCode'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['Chr'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['Start'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['End'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['Alt'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['Ref'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['zygosity'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['gene'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['Func'].'></td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['GeneContext'].'</td>
                                          <td>'.$record_gene['Dist'].'</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    ';
                                 ++$index;
                                 };
                           ?>

                        </tbody>
                   </table>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>


             <script 
                 src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
                 integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" 
                 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/DB/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/DB/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
             <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
             $('.table').DataTable();

              });
             </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: give the table an id and try it via id-selector rather than class selector:  `$('#tableId').DataTable();`

Comment: _sidenote:_ I think `<b><td>..</td></b>` is invalid. `<b>` needs to be inside the <td>

Comment: I already tried to give table an id but still, it doesn't work.
And thank you for the correction about <b>, but this is not the point

Comment: Take a look at [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: I am not entirerly sure that you should do `$record_gene=mysql_fetch_array($result_gene);` and then do `while ($record_gene=mysql_fetch_array($result_gene)){` even if it is valid by some miracle. I am guessing here, but you only need `while ($record_gene=mysql_fetch_array($result_gene)){` in your code.

Comment: yes, you're definitely right! but anyway this doesn't solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: are you sure Datatables is even loaded? I doubt this `src="file:///C|/xampp/.../jquery.dataTables.min.js"` will somehow work. If, then `file:///C:/xampp/...` (rather have those relative anyway, and via http)

Comment: check your console for errors such as `Uncaught ReferenceError: DataTables is not defined`